# checksum used in merge?

Tags: sql-server, merge, checksum

We had a developer that left us last year… He was a great one! As a DBA I liked a lot having him in the team!
But I came across this piece of code from him:

```
when matched and
                    checksum(TARGET.Lead_ID, TARGET.Salesforce_id)          <> checksum(SOURCE.Lead_ID,SOURCE.Salesforce_id)
            or      checksum(TARGET.Lead_ID, TARGET.CreatedById)            <> checksum(SOURCE.Lead_ID,SOURCE.CreatedById)
            or      checksum(TARGET.Lead_ID, TARGET.Email)                  <> checksum(SOURCE.Lead_ID,SOURCE.Email)
            or      checksum(TARGET.Lead_ID, TARGET.LastModifiedById)       <> checksum(SOURCE.Lead_ID,SOURCE.LastModifiedById)         
            or      checksum(TARGET.Lead_ID, TARGET.ConvertedContactId)     <> checksum(SOURCE.Lead_ID,SOURCE.ConvertedContactId)
            or      checksum(TARGET.Lead_ID, TARGET.ConvertedDate)          <> checksum(SOURCE.Lead_ID,SOURCE.ConvertedDate)
            or      checksum(TARGET.Lead_ID, TARGET.ConvertedOpportunityId) <> checksum(SOURCE.Lead_ID,SOURCE.ConvertedOpportunityId)
            or      TARGET.IsConverted                                      <> SOURCE.IsConverted           
            or      checksum(TARGET.Lead_ID, TARGET.Mini_West_Local_Marketing__c) <> checksum(SOURCE.Lead_ID,SOURCE.Mini_West_Local_Marketing__c)
            or      checksum(TARGET.Lead_ID, TARGET.Valid_Leads__c)         <> checksum(SOURCE.Lead_ID,SOURCE.Valid_Leads__c)
            or      checksum(TARGET.Lead_ID, TARGET.FE_Owner__c)            <> checksum(SOURCE.Lead_ID,SOURCE.FE_Owner__c)
            or      checksum(TARGET.Lead_ID, TARGET.FE_Sales_Group__c)          <> checksum(SOURCE.Lead_ID,SOURCE.FE_Sales_Group__c)
```

I know checksum: “returns the checksum value computed over a row of a table, or over a list of expressions. CHECKSUM is intended for use in building hash indexes.’.

But, why would he use it there?

note: (This is a part of the code, the real ‘when matched’ clause had 100 columns, both source and target have 100 columns…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is he's trying to "quickly" detect changes while avoiding `NULL` semantics at the same time.

Not exactly sure why he'd write it that way when using (`EXISTS` + `EXCEPT`) or (`NOT EXISTS` + `INTERSECT`) appears to accomplish the same results without N branches and N * 2 `CHECKSUM` operations:

```
when matched
 and exists (
         select [SOURCE].[Lead_ID]
              , [SOURCE].[Salesforce_id]
              , [SOURCE].[CreatedById]
              , ...
         except
         select [TARGET].[Lead_ID]
              , [TARGET].[Salesforce_id]
              , [TARGET].[CreatedById]
              , ...
     )
```

Comment: Thanks Kittoes0124! I think you are right, but even more… The Source we are are using for the Merge is a: "From SourceTable  Where UpdateDate > @LastUpdateDate " … So there is no need to do any check: if a record was pulled and matched, its because it was updated in the source… I will change it to a “when matched then UPDATE”… Any potential issue/warning I might be missing? I will be completely relying on UpdateDate being used correctly at the source.

Comment: @Chicago1988 if you know for certain that there's no need to perform the check then don't. There's no sense in wasting CPU cycles now if you've already spent them in an earlier part of the process. I use the `exists`/`except` pattern only in situations where I don't know if the incoming values are different or not **and** I want to avoid mutating unchanged columns for some reason (audit, size).